# How to fix string conversion to date?

Tags: informatica-powercenter

my requirement is to convert a string field to date in filter transformation so that i could further compare it with another date but unable to fix the conversion.

Below is the code which i tried .In which i am firstly checking whether it's the correct date format or not using "IS_DATE". This expression is not giving error and being parsed successfully but when i try to convert it to date, it's giving Error "assignment error, Incompatible data types. Field is integer expression is date/time". Not sure what's wrong if "IS_DATE" function is working fine.

IIF(IS_DATE(HIRE_DATE,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS' ),TO_DATE(HIRE_DATE,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS' ))

Comment: Looks like you are trying to assign this expression to a Integer port? You will have to change the port type to date/time.

Answer (score 0):

Change the port type to date. Currently it would be int.